# Spark: convert large input to rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I read a lot of lines from an iterator and I need to convert them to an RDD.

I have see some answers like do an *sc.parallelize(YourIterable.toList)* but the toList will raise a memory exception

I have also read post saying that it is again Spark model but I think there should be another solution.

**I have two ideas, please tell me which is the best or if you have any other ideas to solve this.**

**Solution 1:** I store those lines 100 000 by 100 000 to an ArrayBuffer then when the iterator is empty I convert the array to an RDD with parallelize

```
val result = ArrayBuffer[String]()
var counter = 0
var resultRDD:RDD[Array[Option[Any]]] = sc.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Array[Option[Any]]]
while (resultSet.next()) {
  //Do some stuff on resultSet
  result.append(stuff)
  counter = counter + 1
  if(counter % 100000 == 0){
    val tmp = sc.sparkContext.parallelize(result)
    tmp.count // Need to run an action because result will be cleared
    resultRDD = resultRDD union sc.sparkContext.parallelize(result)
    result.clear
  }
}
// Same for last lines

//use resultRDD
```

With this method the use of count to force an action on the lazy union before the arrayBuffer.clear is a bit annoying.

**Solution 2:** Same bunch reads but write in some files in HDFS and next do a *sc.textFiles*

Comment: Can you add what you are trying to do ?

Comment: Find the best way to convert an large iterator (millions of lines) to an RDD

Comment: Why would you need that, you are not going with the sparks way. But If you really need this I think you could do with the spark streaming.  Where are these iterator from ?

Comment: Solution 2 seems to be feasible. Just store all your data in HDFS, Spark will take care of the rest. No need to partition in small files.

Comment: Iterator can come from a DB or other services with a bounded number of lines (not a web stream like twitter for example). Can i do that with spark Streaming an then transform the stream to a "static" rdd?

Comment: It looks like you are accessing a relational database. If that's the case, you can use the `JdbcRDD` (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD@<init>(sc:org.apache.spark.SparkContext,getConnection:()=>java.sql.Connection,sql:String,lowerBound:Long,upperBound:Long,numPartitions:Int,mapRow:java.sql.ResultSet=>T)(implicitevidence$1:scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]):org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD[T]) or even better the `"jdbc"` format in Spark SQL (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases).

Comment: As i said the iterator may comes from an SQL DB but I want a generic method. For jdbcRDD it is unusable because you need to have an integer/long column with ID nicely spread go get parallelism. For the other you have to be in Spark2 which is unfortunately not possible today for me.

Comment: @Benjamin - Finally which solution worked for you. I took have same requirement to process stored procedure --> rdd --> to parquet

Comment: Sorry @jai, I cannot remember where and why I needed this. It was 1 year ago ;-)